# Using non primitive types in ServiceOperation for WCF Data Service (3.5SP1)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

Is there any way at all to create a "mock" entity type for use in a WCF Service Operation?

We have some queries we do that we need to optimize by exposing as a ServiceOperation.  The problem is in order to do so we would result in a very long list of primitative types...

Ex

```
  SomeoneHelpMe(int time, string name, string address, string i, string purple, string foo, int stillGoing, int tooMany, etc...)
```

And we really need to reduce this to

```
 SomeoneHelpedMe(CustomEntityNotMappedToAnything e)
```

This would also help us when it comes time to write some complex queries since there is a 3 param limitation...

I saw this will be possible in 4.0 using "complex types", but i am still in the 3.5SP1 world.

Let me know if anyone needs more information.

So this is confirmed not possible in 3.5 or 4.0!
Officially its a no!

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/771587aa-0822-4991-8a3f-0091de044b5c

Comment: i'm assuming by all the quietness around this question that it is not possible.... ;(

Comment: If "complex types" are available in 4.0 it might be possible that they are also in the WCF DataServices Update for 3.5SP1: http://blogs.msdn.com/astoriateam/archive/2010/01/27/data-services-update-for-net-3-5-sp1-available-for-download.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/astoriateam/archive/2009/12/17/getting-started-with-the-data-services-update-for-net-3-5-sp1-part-1.aspx . Many features which are in 4.0 are in this Update but I don't know if really all features.

Comment: By the way: For questions about WCF DataServices the MS forum is often a better place to ask than SO: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/threads . The MS guys there are really active and helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this currently - both in 3.5SP1 and 4.0. Only primitive types are supported as parameters for service operations.

Use the following link to add this as a feature request: https://connect.microsoft.com/data/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=WCF%2bData%2bServices. You need to sign in and then you can see the list of bugs/features that have been reported externally. You can add in a new feature request or vote for an existing feature request.

Thanks
Pratik

Comment: joy, i thought this was possible by modeling complex types in 4.0 ?

Comment: confirmation from microsoft http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/771587aa-0822-4991-8a3f-0091de044b5c

Comment: following up though because i have read it is possible http://samuelmueller.com/2009/11/working-with-projections-and-dtos-in-wcf-data-services/

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN site suggests serializing the complex type.

"Any data of a non-primitive type must be serialized and passed into a string parameter." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668788.aspx